# Set theory question about countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\omega\cup\omega^{2}\cup$... is countable

**References**

...a set is called denumerable (countable)if it is in
one-to-one correspondence with ω.

6.1 Definition By the set of the natural numbers we mean the intersection of all the successor sets. The set of the natural numbers is designated by the symbol ω; every element of ω is called a natural number.

$\approx$= equipotent

7.20 Theorem ω × ω ≈ ω.

7.10 Theorem If A ≈ B and C ≈ D, then A × C ≈ B × D.
————————————————————————————————

I believe it has to be done  by induction  by repeatedly using 7.20,and 7.10 and the fact a union of countable sets is countable.

I think AoC comes into too.
Is my reasoning correct? The only thing I
can’t get is mapping for something continuous like this

Base case

By 7.20 and the fact that countable union of countable sets are countable $\omega \cup \omega^{2}$ is countable

Induction step:
We want to show that $\bigcup\omega^{n^{+}}$
is countable...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe change your title to something more precise

Comment: By $\omega^2$ do you mean the ordinal $\omega^2$, or do you mean the Cartesian product $\omega\times\omega$? It makes a difference to the details of the argument.

Comment: I guess Cartesian product ,haven’t gotten to ordinals yet @BrianMScott

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use more descriptive titles. After reading your title users have no idea what your question is about, it's a useless title.

Comment: Changed it to something better @jjagmath . Can I get a better rating ?

Comment: You changed the title to other that also doesn't give any clue what your question is about. You surely can do better.

Try something that include words like "countable", "union", something RELATED to the question.

Comment: I just did @jjagmath

Comment: That's better, thank you.

Comment: Now, a hint about your problem. Prove first that $\omega^n \approx \omega$

Comment: I did that in a previous exercise @jjagmath

Comment: If you already know that each $\omega^n$ is countable. Then you have a countable union of countable sets....

Answer (score 1):

Given that $\omega^n$ is countably infinite, 7.10 and 7.20 tell you that $\omega^{n+1}$ is countably infinite, so by induction $\omega^n$ is countably infinite for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. If you’ve already proved that the union of countably many countable sets is countable, you’re done at that point. Otherwise, you’ll have to prove that the union is countable. For instance, for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ you could let $f_n:\omega\to\omega^n$ be a bijection and then define

$$h:\omega\times\omega\to\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\omega^n:\langle m,n\rangle\mapsto f_{m^+}(n)$$

and show that it is a bijection.

Comment: That is a given theorem. 7.22 I believe.

Comment: @Eudoxus: In that case you really are done once you do the induction. The induction step is just using 7.10 and 7.20 to say that $$|\omega^{n+1}|=|\omega^n\times\omega|=|\omega\times\omega|=|\omega|\,.$$